# How to use Task.WaitAll to wait both tasks

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have the following code which calls 2 async methods and wait for results:

```
private Task FirstTaskAsync() {
...
}
private Task SecondTaskAsync() {
...
}

private async void Caller() {
   await FirstTaskAsync();
   await SecondTaskAsync();
}
```

Problem is it now executes and waits for each task sequentially. I want to change it to Task.WaitAll(). Here is my change:

```
private async void Caller() {
   var first = FirstTaskAsync();
   var second = SecondTaskAsync();

   Task.WaitAll(first, second);
}
```

But when I test it, Task.WaitAll() never returns.  Can you please tell me what is missing?

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but...did you start the tasks? If that's not it, I think you need to post a more complete example. As in, an actually-complete (but still concise) example.

Comment: To be closer to the original code, you should use `await Task.WhenAll(first, second)`

Comment: My guess is either `FirstTaskAsync` or `SecondTAskAsync` is not returning. Post their implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you should never do `async void` unless you are doing a event handler (which I doubt you are), if you did `async Task` it makes it more obvious what your problem is.

```
private async Task Caller() {
   await FirstTaskAsync();
   await SecondTaskAsync();
}

//This still will not work...
private async Task Caller() {
   var first = FirstTaskAsync();
   var second = SecondTaskAsync();

   Task.WaitAll(first, second);
}
```

`Task.WaitAll` returns void and you never use `await` in the second method, so you are executing the code synchronously and blocking on the `SynchronizationContext` [which will cause you to get deadlocks like you are seeing.](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

The correct solution would be not to block but instead use [`Task.WhenAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160374%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which returns a Task itself which allows you to drop the async keyword and just return the result

```
private Task Caller() {
   var first = FirstTaskAsync();
   var second = SecondTaskAsync();

   return Task.WhenAll(first, second);
}
```

However, if `Caller()` really is a event handler you can also do `async void` and just await the result.

```
private async void Caller() { //This should only be done if this is a event handler.
   var first = FirstTaskAsync();
   var second = SecondTaskAsync();

   await Task.WhenAll(first, second);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
private async void Caller() 
{
    Task[] tasks = new Task[2];
    tasks[0] = FirstTaskAsync();
    tasks[1] = SecondTaskAsync();

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Comment: `WhenAll` uses the params keyword, so you don't have to create the array by hand.

Comment: It would be good to explain why this work when the OP's solution deadlocks.